# I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to use axios.post, but the error [object Object] is returning, I don't know where I'm going wrong

Tags: reactjs

API body:

### {
"title":"Cortar a grama",
"description":"Manutenção em áreas verdes de até 1000 metros quadrados.",
"price":40,
"paymentMethods":["PayPal", "boleto"],
"dueDate":"2021-12-30"
}

Below part of the code:

state = {
title: "",
description: "",
price: "",
paymentMethods: [],
dueDate: "",
}

```
changeTitle = (e) => {
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value })
}

changeDescription = (e) => {
    this.setState({ description: e.target.value })
}

changePrice = (e) => {
    this.setState({ price: e.target.value })
}

changePaymentMethods = (e) => {
    this.setState({ paymentMethods: e.target.value })
}

changeDueDate = (e) => {
    this.setState({ dueDate: e.target.value })
}

registerService = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const body = {
        title: this.state.title,
        description: this.state.description,
        price: this.state.price,
        paymentMethods: this.state.paymentMethods,
        dueDate: this.state.dueDate
    }

    axios.post(baseUrl, body, axiosConfig)
        .then(() => {
            alert('Oferta de serviço cadastrada com sucesso')
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err.response.data)
            console.log(err.response.data)
        })

    this.setState({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        price: "",
        paymentMethods: [],
        dueDate: ""
    })
}
```

Comment: hi, could you try console logging just `err` instead of `err.response.data`? Also, could you try editting your question with the `baseUrl` and `axiosConfig` values?

Answer (score 0):

Something is failing in your axios.post call and you are not being able to read the error correctly. I guess you are getting [Object Object] error on your alert function, but your console.log is probably displaying your error correctly.

I'd say that there's something wrong with your url or config.
You may try do do some things to investigate this error:

1 - Try the POST action on Postman, if you know how to use it;

2 - Check the api docs to verify if you don't nedd specific credentials to post it of if something is missing;

3 - Change your alert

```
alert(err.response.data);
```

to:

```
alert(err);
```

or if you want the data object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
```

4 - Change your *console.log* to *console.dir*, this would giive you access to the attributes of the object

```
console.dir(err.response.data); // or console.dir(err);
```

Doing these steps could help you to understand what is failing on your request and correct the issue.